# CUDA-GDB view variables in C/C++

Tags: c++, cuda, ubuntu-16.04, cuda-gdb

I have installed the latest version of the CUDA drivers available from NVIDIA

```
mmiller@host:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

But when I debug a program I get an error message about python.

```
mmiller@csit-crackin:~$ cuda-gdb hello.out
NVIDIA (R) CUDA Debugger
7.5 release
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/mmiller/hello.out...done.
(cuda-gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402546: file hello.cu, line 3.
(cuda-gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mmiller/hello.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.cu:3
3       foo:    int x = 1;
(cuda-gdb) s
4               int y = x+1;
(cuda-gdb) p x
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'gdb.Type' object has no attribute 'name':
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'gdb.Type' object has no attribute 'name':
$1 = 1
(cuda-gdb)
```

I the program is a very simple program and I read that it may be an error dealing with python and gdb, but I am unsure of how to fix the error using the latest software from Ubuntu and Nvidia.  Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: 1. upgrade to cuda 8.  Problems get fixed all the time.  2. Provide a complete test case so someone else could try to reproduce your observation.  I use cuda-gdb frequently and have not run into this issue.

Comment: You may be observing something similar to what is reported [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/994231/cuda-gdb/python-exception-lt-type-exceptions-attributeerror-gt-gdb-type-object-has-no-attribute-name-/).  That issue has already been reported as a bug to NVIDIA.  It's not clear that it is a NVIDIA bug, but if it is, a fix may not be immediately forthcoming - it may wait until the next CUDA release.  In the meantime, a couple comments: 1. Try a vanilla load of the OS and CUDA (e.g. a clean load of Ubuntu 16.04 if that is what you are using).  Don't update python.

Comment: 2. It's not entirely clear that this issue prevents forward progress.  Although you are getting those Python Exception messages, it seems that cuda-gdb has not crashed and in fact printed what you asked for (`$1 = 1`). So it's possible it may be a nuisance but not a showstopper issue.  I can't be sure since I can't reproduce it myself at the moment.

Comment: So, I had updated CUDA to 8, but it appears that ubuntu did not update the path to use the newest version of CUDA-GDB.  That fixes the error.

Comment: @Milhous: Would you like to add a short answer to this question to that effect so that it falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Ubuntu will not update the path to include the latest version of nvcc and cuda-gdb.  You have to update the path (or change the symlinks) manually for your to reference the correct versions of these libraries.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to do this. I'm rather new to cuda programming